# Cannot login again since 6 days!

Tags: login

I have delete timeshift complete with `sudo apt remove timeshift`
and I set the root-reserved percentage on the root filesystem from 5% to 0% because
here (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1738065) it descript exactly my problem but I get the crisis because I can't login more.  :x

My Login PW is REALLY the same and it blinking 2 times and jump back so there is something other: x  :x  :x  :x  :x

Comment: After i start Linux in Live-System again i see Timeshift again, too.  :|

Answer (score 2):

If your disk is 100% full, then then X11 GUI login procedure cannot create/update a `~/.Xauthority` file for your session. Press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to see a text-based login prompt: text-based login should be successful even with a 100% full disk.

Then use `sudo rm -r /timeshift` to remove the Timeshift backup data. **Uninstalling the Timeshift application with `sudo apt remove timeshift` will not remove the backup data, only the backup application itself.**

Comment: Thank you! I have delete all backup folder because Larry from Linuxmint Forum call it to me before but it dont help. Now i do it after normal start in strg alt F1 area and there it ask me for other login data names "mint" so i must know the login name and password but what is it?

Comment: Now i find its mint and empty pw after i give this code it answer NO SUCH FILE OR DIRECTORY

Comment: Raging won't make it easier for us to help you, but getting more information might. First, run `df -h`. Is your disk actually 100% full or not? If not, it's time to look at various log files. `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` might be useful. If your home directory contains a hidden `.Xsession-errors` file (or something similar), and its timestamp gets updated each time you attempt a GUI login, then that file very likely includes an error message that would describe what exactly is going wrong with your login. If you can edit that information into your question, we might be able to tell you how to fix it.

Comment: Yes but it help to lost stress and make more -.- There is written aufs Size 5.8 Used 15M Avail 5.7G Use% 1 Mounted on /